# How to force .vue extension in all imports using eslint?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vetur

In VS Code with [Vetur](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/) (the extension for working with Vue), "Go to definition" will not work on component imports where there's no `.vue` extension at the end ([Vetur FAQ link](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/commit/562d1ff995c5370a2bbaa481c0eda3c1e154ca8d))

I was wondering if there's an eslint rule that will force the user to always provide an extension when using an `import` statement in `.vue` files?

Examples:

- ✔️ This works:

  ```js
    import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
  ```

  Right clicking on `HelloWorld` and pressing `Go to definition` in VS Code wil take you to the `HelloWorld.vue` file.
- ❌ This doesn't:

  ```js
  import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
  ```

  If you press `Go to definition` on `HelloWorld` (leftmost), VS Code will just move the cursor to the `HelloWorld` you just right clicked. Intended behavior is that we move to the `HelloWorld.vue` file.

Answer (score 9):

It's easy to do this for paths like `./src/components/A.vue`. It's trickier for `@/components/A.vue` because you need to resolve the `@` alias.

The below solution works for both.

#### To force `.vue` extensions in paths, do this:

**1.** Install `eslint-plugin-import`, which extends functionality of eslint by linting import paths. Also install with a custom path resolver - `eslint-import-resolver-alias` for it:

```sh
npm install eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-alias --save-dev
```

**2.** Then, in your `ESLint` config file (`.eslintrc.js`, or `eslintConfig` field in `package.json` etc), add this:

```js
// I'm using .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
//...unimportant properties like root, env, extends, parserOptions etc
  plugins: ["import"],
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ["@", "./src"], //default @ -> ./src alias in Vue, it exists even if vue.config.js is not present
          /* 
          *... add your own webpack aliases if you have them in vue.config.js/other webpack config file
          * if you forget to add them, eslint-plugin-import will not throw linting error in .vue imports that contain the webpack alias you forgot to add
          */
        ],
        extensions: [".vue", ".json", ".js"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's [a repository with a working demo](https://github.com/sethidden/demo-vue-eslint-force-dot-vue-extension-in-imports) that implements forcing .vue path in imports correctly.

And a screenshot from VSCode and output from `npm run lint`:

[image: eslint errors regarding missing .vue path showing up in vscode problems view and in terminal output after running npm run lint]

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure `eslint-plugin-import` to set force on `vue` files, just add this rule in eslint config

```json
"import/extensions": ["error", "ignorePackages", { "vue": "always" }],
```

Comment: This does not work for `.vue` files. Check out my comment under the original question. I've filed an issue. It works for .js files as intended though

Comment: @ArturTagisow I'm using this rule in my project and it works. I'm using version `^2.18.2`

Comment: Hmm, are you using Vue with JavaScript or TypeScript? I'm using TS

Comment: @ArturTagisow JS, give me a time to test it on TS

Comment: I had to revisit this again lately. Using this with webpack aliases (@ in the path in my original question) is a nightmare and I couldn't get it to work in a Vue CLI project. I also created https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1533. Its possible you need to install `eslint-import-resolver-webpack` and define the webpack aliases there, see: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/tree/master/resolvers/webpack

Comment: @ArturTagisow Hi, man, how did you solve it, after configured node and webpack plugin for eslint-import, mine is still not working

Comment: @Wenfang I got it working. Check out my answer below.

Comment: @ArturTagisow There are a few issues, https://github.com/3nuc/demo-vue-eslint-force-dot-vue-extension-in-imports/issues/1